# Acknowledging a worker for accolades given by outside party

Tags: people-management

A contractor asked me,"So what did you think of the letter I sent your manager?" "What letter?", I replied. My manager has been sitting a a letter from a contractor commending me for my efforts to get a project done. It has been about three weeks and she has said nothing to me. The contractor got a short reply thanking them for their input so i know my manager received the correspondence. This is not the first time my manager has kept silent after receiving such an accolade towards me. What am I to do? This kind of thing should be acknowledged and a copy entered into my personnel file. Is there any way to force her hand?

Comment: When you say "*should*" do you refer to some established rules or just your preferences?

Comment: You don't know the it did not go in you personal file.

Answer (score 5):

I'm sorry to be the bearer of bad news, but I don't think there's anything you can do.

Either your manager thinks that the praise is inconsequential, or plain doesn't like you. Either way she's a terrible manager.

You can't really force her hand, because the customer will most likely rarely tell you about it after the fact. What are you going to do? Regularly go up to her and ask whether you've received praise?

You *could* have a conversation about this sort of situation and tell her that you'd appreciate if such praise was passed on to you in the future, but realistically, it would probably be perceived as a slap in her face, and won't over well.

Comment: Really inconsequential or plain doesn't like you. Either way a terrible manager.   Your views are absolute with reaching assumptions.   You don't know the manager did not just put it in the confidential employee file.

Comment: @paparazzi - It's a free country, right? Or a "free" site, at any rate? I would like to point out that any manager who is not completely self absorbed, absent minded, or plain _mean_ would take a minute to congratulate a well performing employee, or team. ***Especially*** when the customer bothered to write her an email about it. And chances are that if she can't be bothered to do that she hasn't silently done anything other than ignore it after having received it.

Comment: Again you don't know a note was not entered in the personnel file and your views tend to be absolute.   "Self absorbed, absent minded, or plain *mean*" - you don't get that is just just a bit out there in emotion and assumption?  And yes this a site where I also can voice an opinion.

Comment: @Paparazzi - by all means, voice your opinion. I rather like my "absolute" and "a bit out there in emotion" views. I tend to think of them as "decisive" though. That being said, to each their own. If you think that my answer is lacking in some aspect or another you could always try providing us with a post of your own :-)

Comment: Cool. I did not vote you down. You are a good writer.

Answer (score 5):

Next time, see if you can get the customer to send you a cc of the praise (which they really should have done without being promoted). Then you and your manager will both have copies, and both be aware that the other has a copy, which should make the conversation easier.

Re other comments, standard reminder to not assume malace. Maybe the manager is assuming you *did* get a copy, and just isn't good about remembering to say "hey, they like you, well done." Not every manager has good vpeople skills, alas.

Comment: maybe the manager just assumed that the client had bcc the employee.

Answer (score 3):

The manager is not doing her job properly. Letters like this are morale boosters for a whole team as well as they reflect well on her as your manager, so should definitely be mentioned. But psychoanalysing her motivations isn't constructive.

Not a lot you can do about it either, the fault is mainly with the manager and partly with the client. The client should have cc'd you.

Personally I would just shrug it off and file the information away until I have a use for it.